# Mongoose: ValidatorError: Path is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to make a registration in MongoDB with Mongoose, and I get this error, it probably has to do with the type of data that I am saving in the collection, which is generating this conflict.

The error

```
Error: User validation failed: name: Cast to string failed for value "{...}" at path "name", surname: Path `surname` is required., email: Path `email` is required., birth: Path `birth` is required., password: Path `password` is required.
```

And My Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);
const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: 'Please enter your name',
            unique: true,
            trim: true
        },
        surname:{
            type:String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        email:{
            type:String,
            required: true,
        },
        birth:{
            type:Date,
            required: true  
        },
        password:{
            type:String,
            required: true,
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
userSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {id:'order_seq',inc_field: 'order'});
module.exports = model('User', userSchema);
```

This is where I do the query, the error gives me to understand that all the fields are not being admitted by the collection

```
const userCtrl = {};

const User = require('../models/User');

userCtrl.createUser = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
        const { username } = req.body;
        console.log(username);
        const newUser = new User({
            name:req.body.name,
            surname:req.body.surname,
            email:req.body.email,
            birth:req.body.birth,
            password:req.body.password,
        });
        await newUser.save();
        res.json('User created');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.json(e.errmsg);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you are not posting any data, which is why
This means your `req.body` object most likely do not have surname, email, birth, and password.

And you have specified them as "required" fields in your Schema. This means mongoose will not create the user, if the fields are null. Unless you specify a default value.

```
surname: Path `surname` is required., email: Path `email` is required., birth: Path `birth` is required., password: Path `password` is required.
```